# entropy relation between ads$_2$ black hole and near extremal ads RN black brane

Tags: gravity, string-theory, black-holes, entropy

It seems that the entropy for AdS$_2$ black hole is independent of the temperature $s=s_0$. While for near extremal AdS RN black brane, $s=s_0+ s(T/\mu)$. Should not these two entropies be the same since the AdS$_2$ black hole can be thought of a near horizon geometry of near extremal AdS RN black brane?